# How to make when i get big data user to know the method is running without freeze?

Tags: c#, wpf, freeze

I have a method that may take a long time to finish. I want to prevent my program from freezing while this method is running.

What can I do to show the user it is running the method (for example a progress bar)?

Comment: If the method is asynchronous it should not freeze anyway...

Comment: I am sorry i wrote wrongly.If i dont use asynchronous method it will freeze,how to make user to know method is running?

Answer (score 1):

First of all as H.B said if the method is running asynchronously in some background thread then your UI won't freeze.

If you want a progress bar on your UI that can tell user how much progress has completed then you can use [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) functionality of a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: prgoress bar shows how many percents completed,i cannot do that,because i dont know how to get that percent.it maybe there is a loading ui for this

Comment: If you just want to show in progress kind of thing use the event that raises when BackgroundWorker has completed i.e. `BackgroundWorker.Completed`.

Comment: you dont understand me,i know when it finishes,but dont know working time

Answer (score 0):

You should use BackgroundWorker class. Its better then pure threads because it does some additional stuff. Cant remember right now, that was a long time I have done WPF. This code will help you:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.progressBar1.Value++; }));
        }
    }
```